# VS2017: cannot add strings/wstrings

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have trouble understanding why the following code does not do what it should, VS2017 does not show an error and the solution is created, but the string is never what it should be:

```
void COrion::AddJournalMessage(CTextData *msg, const string &name)
{
    WISPFUN_DEBUG("c194_f101");
    CTextData *jmsg = new CTextData(msg);

    jmsg->Text = name + jmsg->Text;
}
```

jmsg->Text is std::string.

now at runtime let's say 'name' is "Player:" and 'jmsg->Text' is "Hello World", I would expect the text after the code to be "Player:Hello World", but it is not. It's only "Player:" and I don't understand why.

I found a workaround in a way:

```
jmsg->Text = name.c_str() + jmsg->Text;
```

with this change it is "Player:Hello World".

Problem is, I still don't understand why the first one does not work.
Can someone explain where the problem is?
Is it specific to VS or something?

to make it clear: this is from an open source project I want to use, not code I wrote myself, but the problem has been the source of many bugs, since it is used in this way alot.

*edit*
CTextData class:

```
class CTextData : public CRenderTextObject
{
public:
    bool Unicode = false;
    TEXT_TYPE Type = TT_CLIENT;
    uchar Font = 0;
    uint Timer = 0;
    uint MoveTimer = 0;
    string Text = "";
    wstring UnicodeText = L"";
    uchar Alpha = 0xFF;
    CRenderWorldObject *Owner = NULL;
    CTextData();
    CTextData(CTextData *obj);
    virtual ~CTextData();

    virtual bool IsText() { return true; }

    bool CanBeDrawedInJournalGump();

    CGLTextTexture m_Texture;

    void GenerateTexture(
        int maxWidth,
        ushort flags = 0,
        TEXT_ALIGN_TYPE align = TS_LEFT,
        uchar cell = 30,
        int font = -1);
};
```

Comment: What library is `CTextData` from? I don't recognize it.

Comment: It's part of the project, I added it in the original post. But I don't think it's related, I have other points in the code with the same problem, where it is no used.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  As things stand it's difficult to give you a useful answer because there's so much we don't know.  We don't know how (or if) `jmsg->text` was set by the `CTextData(CTextData *obj)` constructor.  We don't know how (or if) `msg->Text` was set when `AddJournalMessage` was called.  The simplest explanation for the symptoms you describe would be that `jmsg->text` was set to the empty string.  If you reduce your code to a [mcve] it would help nresolve some of these ambiguities.  See [Tour] and  [ask] for more tips on asking effective questions.